# How can I transpose in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data displayed using the select statement displayed below. but I would like to transpose based on the customer and shipby date and create a single row

```
 PO    CUSTOMER  CUST PN     PN     DESC           QTY    SHIP DATE  
 001     xxx      111     100200    description1    24    2017-06-27
 002     xxx      112     100201    description2    25    2017-06-27
```

I want to see as follows

```
 PO1  PO2    CUSTOMER  CUST PN1  CUST PN2    PN1    PN2      DESC 1     DESC 2             QTY1   QTY2   SHIP DATE  
 001  002     xxx      111       112      100200  100201  description1 description2         24      25   2017-06-27
```

ship date and customer field will be the same

Here is my SQL statement

```
SELECT  
    [PO #], [CUSTOMER], [CUST PN], [PN], [DESC], [QTY], [SHIP DATE]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [PO #], [CUSTOMER], [CUST PN], [PN], [DESC], [QTY], [SHIP DATE]
     FROM 
         WORKORDERS S
     WHERE   
         [SHIP BY] = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106))) AS s
```

Comment: You seem to be making up data in your output. Where does PO3 and PO4 come from? Those values aren't in your sample data. And which ship date do you want? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Looks like you want a Dynamic Pivot... three times... which makes no sense

Comment: @SeanLange my bad i fix it. Thank you

Comment: Rather strange output but you can tackle this easily with a dynamic cross tab. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: since you are trying to keep the  [ship date] and [customer] a single column I don't think you can achieve this without some sort of loop (cursor, while, etc.) or is it possible to still include [customer1] [customer2] and [ship date1] [ship date2]  and then filter them out with view or cte?

Comment: @Milan customer and ship date should be same but i don't affect anything having them separated

Comment: check your description columns on your desired results set. you have the headers as 'description1', 'description2', when per pattern of other columns it should be 'desc1', 'desc2'

Comment: No Problem @user8066749.

Comment: @user8066749 what version of SQL SERVER are you on?

Comment: @chris `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) 
 Feb 20 2014 19:20:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey here is my answer to your puzzle. I Found out an interesting but with SQL Server when it comes to agg columns. See comments at end of script. Also, forgive any messiness in code. Got called twice by the wife to get 'the kid'. Will try and clean up later...

```
DECLARE @workorders AS TABLE
(
    [PO #] NVARCHAR(10),
    [CUSTOMER] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CUST PN] INT,
    [PN] INT,
    [DESC] NVARCHAR(500),
    [QTY] INT,
    [SHIP DATE] DATE
);

--DECLARE @workorders_W_GroupingID AS TABLE
--(
--  groupingID INT,
--    [PO #] NVARCHAR(10),
--    [CUSTOMER] NVARCHAR(200),
--    [CUST PN] INT,
--    [PN] INT,
--    [DESC] NVARCHAR(500),
--    [QTY] INT,
--    [SHIP DATE] DATE
--);



INSERT @workorders
(
    [PO #],
    CUSTOMER,
    [CUST PN],
    PN,
    [DESC],
    QTY,
    [SHIP DATE]
)
VALUES
('001', N'xxx', 111, 100200, N'description1', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('002', N'xxx', 112, 100200, N'description2', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('003', N'xxx', 113, 100200, N'description3', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('004', N'xxx', 114, 100200, N'description4', 24, '2017-06-25'),
('005', N'aaa', 115, 100200, N'description5', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('006', N'aaa', 116, 100200, N'description6', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('007', N'aaa', 117, 100200, N'description7', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('008', N'ccc', 118, 100200, N'description8', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('009', N'xxx', 119, 100200, N'description9', 24, '2017-06-27');

--INSERT INTO @workorders_W_GroupingID
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.CUSTOMER, S.[SHIP DATE] ORDER BY S.[PO #]) AS groupingID,
       S.*
INTO #workorders_W_GroupingID
FROM @workorders S;

SELECT * FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID;--DISPLAY

--COUNTER
DECLARE @CUNTER INT;
DECLARE @MAX_CUNTER INT;
SET @MAX_CUNTER =
(
    SELECT MAX(groupingID) FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID
);

DECLARE @query_Select NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_From NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_Into NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_OrderBy NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query_Select = N'SELECT ';
----PO----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT PO FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'PO' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----CUSTOMER----
SET @query_Select = @query_Select + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN temp.CUSTOMER END AS' + N' customer, ');

----CUST PN----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT [CUST PN] FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'[CUST PN' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + '],');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----PN----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT PN FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'PN' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----DESC----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT [DESC] FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'DESC' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----QTY----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT QTY FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'QTY' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----SHIP DATE----
SET @query_Select = @query_Select + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN temp.[SHIP DATE] END AS' + N'[ship date] ');

SET @query_From = N'FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID AS temp  ';
SET @query_Into = N' INTO ##RESULTS_2017_06_28';
SET @query_OrderBy = N'Order by BY CUSTOMER, [SHIP DATE] ';

SET @query = @query_Select + ' ' + @query_Into + ' ' + @query_From; --+ -- ' ' + @query_GroupBy


 execute (@query);

SELECT * 
FROM ##RESULTS_2017_06_28
WHERE CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL
/*ORDER OF COLUMNS IS WRONG SEE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982286/tsql-string-concat-with-select-and-order-by-does-not-work-with-function-in-order
  Currently do not see a way to fix. Data appears to be correct.
*/

/*
SELECT * 
FROM ##RESULTS_2017_06_28
WHERE CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE 
*/
DROP TABLE #workorders_W_GroupingID, ##RESULTS_2017_06_28;
```

**UPDATED CODE.** Found some more bugs and got the ordering fixed(caused by my bugs). Will leave original code above, but BELOW is the magic ;)

```
--VARIABLES
DECLARE @workorders AS TABLE
(
    [PO] NVARCHAR(10),
    [CUSTOMER] NVARCHAR(200),
    [CUST PN] INT,
    [PN] INT,
    [DESC] NVARCHAR(500),
    [QTY] INT,
    [SHIP DATE] DATE
);

--COUNTER
DECLARE @CUNTER INT;
DECLARE @MAX_CUNTER INT;


--CREATE TEST DATA
INSERT @workorders
(
    [PO],
    CUSTOMER,
    [CUST PN],
    PN,
    [DESC],
    QTY,
    [SHIP DATE]
)
VALUES
('001', N'xxx', 111, 100200, N'description1', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('002', N'xxx', 112, 100200, N'description2', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('003', N'xxx', 113, 100200, N'description3', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('004', N'xxx', 114, 100200, N'description4', 24, '2017-06-25'),
('005', N'aaa', 115, 100200, N'description5', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('006', N'aaa', 116, 100200, N'description6', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('007', N'aaa', 117, 100200, N'description7', 24, '2017-06-28'),
('008', N'ccc', 118, 100200, N'description8', 24, '2017-06-27'),
('009', N'xxx', 119, 100200, N'description9', 24, '2017-06-27');

--INSERT INTO @workorders_W_GroupingID
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.CUSTOMER, S.[SHIP DATE] ORDER BY S.[PO]) AS groupingID,
       S.*
INTO #workorders_W_GroupingID
FROM @workorders S;

SELECT * FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID;--DISPLAY

--INITIALIZE COUNTER VARIABLES
SET @MAX_CUNTER =
(
    SELECT MAX(groupingID) + 1 FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID
);
SET @CUNTER = 1;

DECLARE @query_Select NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_From NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_Into NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query_OrderBy NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query_Select = N'SELECT ';
----PO----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT PO FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'PO' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----CUSTOMER----
SET @query_Select = @query_Select + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN temp.CUSTOMER END AS' + N' customer, ');

----CUST PN----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT [CUST PN] FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'[CUST PN' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + '],');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----PN----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT PN FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'PN' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----DESC----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT [DESC] FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'DESC' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----QTY----
WHILE (@CUNTER < @MAX_CUNTER)
BEGIN
    --ADD COLUMN
    SET @query_Select
        = @query_Select
          + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN (SELECT QTY FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID WHERE  customer = temp.customer AND [ship date] = temp.[ship date] AND GroupingID = '
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ') END AS ' + N'QTY' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @CUNTER) + ',');

    --INCREASE CUNTER
    SET @CUNTER = @CUNTER + 1;
END;
--RESET CUNTER
SET @CUNTER = 1;

----SHIP DATE----
SET @query_Select = @query_Select + (' CASE WHEN temp.groupingID = 1 THEN temp.[SHIP DATE] END AS' + N'[ship date] ');

SET @query_From = N'FROM #workorders_W_GroupingID AS temp  ';
SET @query_Into = N' INTO ##RESULTS_2017_06_28';
SET @query_OrderBy = N'Order by BY CUSTOMER, [SHIP DATE] ';

SET @query = @query_Select + ' ' + @query_Into + ' ' + @query_From; --+ -- ' ' + @query_GroupBy


 execute (@query);

SELECT * 
FROM ##RESULTS_2017_06_28
WHERE CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL
/*ORDER OF COLUMNS IS WRONG SEE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982286/tsql-string-concat-with-select-and-order-by-does-not-work-with-function-in-order
  Currently do not see a way to fix. Data appears to be correct.
*/

/*
SELECT * 
FROM ##RESULTS_2017_06_28
WHERE CUSTOMER IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    CASE 
*/
DROP TABLE #workorders_W_GroupingID, ##RESULTS_2017_06_28;

/*Results
PO1 PO2 PO3 customer    CUST PN1    CUST PN2    CUST PN3    PN1 PN2 PN3 DESC1   DESC2   DESC3   QTY1    QTY2    QTY3    ship date
005 NULL    NULL    aaa 115 NULL    NULL    100200  NULL    NULL    description5    NULL    NULL    24  NULL    NULL    2017-06-27
006 007 NULL    aaa 116 117 NULL    100200  100200  NULL    description6    description7    NULL    24  24  NULL    2017-06-28
008 NULL    NULL    ccc 118 NULL    NULL    100200  NULL    NULL    description8    NULL    NULL    24  NULL    NULL    2017-06-27
004 NULL    NULL    xxx 114 NULL    NULL    100200  NULL    NULL    description4    NULL    NULL    24  NULL    NULL    2017-06-25
001 002 009 xxx 111 112 119 100200  100200  100200  description1    description2    description9    24  24  24  2017-06-27
003 NULL    NULL    xxx 113 NULL    NULL    100200  NULL    NULL    description3    NULL    NULL    24  NULL    NULL    2017-06-28
*/
```

Comment: Thanks alot Chris!! how can i insert the value into another table

Comment: The records are in the ##Results_2017_06_28 table. You can use an 'insert into' but since we dont know what the columns are at the time of execution, we have to use '*'. I was trying to figure out a way to at least get them in correct order but is proving to be impossible right now. Is this going to get use by an application?

Comment: Thank you Chris Working Great. can i create a trigger on this when `ship date`=getdate()?`

Comment: Why are you wanting to make a trigger? I'm new to being a DBA but one thing I have been told and have seen is Triggers can be really bad(hides complexity as it creates complexity) and in most cases can be avoided easily creating a better solution.

Comment: to trigger the insert every day or hour

Comment: you want a sql job, not a trigger. sql agent jobs are easy to set up and there is plenty of info out online on how to. :)